# How Can I Merge All Duplicates In Array Based On One Key's Value?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, t-sql, php-5.6

I have tried all kinds of solutions, and none seem to do what I need- or I don't understand how to morph them to solve my particular problem. Basically, I am returning a bunch of rows from my SQL server. The query looks like this:

```
$params = array(&$search, &$search, &$search, &$search, &$search, &$search, &$search, &$search);

$tsql = "SELECT Item.ID, Item.ItemLookupCode, nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber, SupplierList.ReorderNumber, Item.Notes,
         Item.Description, Item.ExtendedDescription, Item.Quantity, nitroasl_pamtable.SpoofStock, Item.Price,
         nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords, Item.PictureName
         FROM Item
         INNER JOIN nitroasl_pamtable ON Item.ID = nitroasl_pamtable.ItemID
         INNER JOIN SupplierList ON Item.ID = SupplierList.ItemID
         WHERE (Item.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (Item.ID LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (SupplierList.ReorderNumber LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (Item.Notes LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (Item.Description LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (Item.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
         OR (nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%' + ? + '%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)";

// Allows us to determine the number of rows returned
$cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params, $cursorType);
```

I then use the following to put the rows into an array:

```
// Put results into an array
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $results['results'][] = $row;
}
```

**$results['results']** looks like this when I search "***tp-ac1750*** (Removed some returned columns for easier viewing):

```
Array (

  [results] => Array (

    [0] => Array (

      [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750

      [ReorderNumber] => ARCHERC7

    )

    [1] => Array (

      [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750

      [ReorderNumber] => N82E16833704177

    )

    [2] => Array (

      [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750

      [ReorderNumber] => 7681617

    )

    [3] => Array (

      [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750

      [ReorderNumber] => ARCHERC7

    )

  )

  [keywords] => tp-ac1750

)
```

I would like the array to look like this:

```
Array (

  [results] => Array (

    [0] => Array (

      [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750

      [ReorderNumber] => Array (

        [0] => ARCHERC7

        [1] => N82E16833704177

        [2] => 7681617

      )

    )

  )

)
```

I have tried:

- array_unique
- array_unique_recursive
- array_walk_recursive
- array_merge_recursive
- And more (various combinations)

But I cannot seem to get it right. Here is what I am trying now:

```
// Remove duplicates
$results['results'] = merge_duplicates( $results['results'] );

//***********************************************
// Merge duplicate arrays and their values
//***********************************************
function merge_duplicates( $array )
{

  // Build temporary array for array_unique
  $tmp = array();
  foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $tmp[ $key ] = $value;
  }

  // Find duplicates in temporary array
  $tmp = array_unique( $tmp, SORT_REGULAR );

  // Remove duplicates from original array
  foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {

    if ( !array_key_exists( $key, $tmp ) ) {

      unset( $array[ $key ] );

    }

  }

  return $array;

}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this type of merge? Is there a way to merge these duplicates during the SQL query? Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

## Update (Full Array Being Worked With)

Here is the actual array I need to use this merge on (I still want to use ItemLookupCode as the unique key, but merge all the other sibling keys):

```
Array (

  [0] => Array (

    [ID] => 8265
    [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750
    [ManufacturerPartNumber] => Archer C7
    [ReorderNumber] => ARCHERC7
    [Notes] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [Description] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [ExtendedDescription] => TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless-AC1750 Dual-Band Gigabit Router
    [Quantity] => 0
    [SpoofStock] =>
    [Price] => 129.9500
    [PAM_Keywords] =>
    [PictureName] => tp-ac1750.jpg

  )

  [1] => Array (

    [ID] => 8265
    [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750
    [ManufacturerPartNumber] => Archer C7
    [ReorderNumber] => N82E16833704177
    [Notes] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [Description] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [ExtendedDescription] => TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless-AC1750 Dual-Band Gigabit Router
    [Quantity] => 0
    [SpoofStock] =>
    [Price] => 129.9500
    [PAM_Keywords] =>
    [PictureName] => tp-ac1750.jpg

  )

  [2] => Array (

    [ID] => 8265
    [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750
    [ManufacturerPartNumber] => Archer C7
    [ReorderNumber] => 7681617
    [Notes] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [Description] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [ExtendedDescription] => TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless-AC1750 Dual-Band Gigabit Router
    [Quantity] => 0
    [SpoofStock] =>
    [Price] => 129.9500
    [PAM_Keywords] =>
    [PictureName] => tp-ac1750.jpg

  )

  [3] => Array (

    [ID] => 8265
    [ItemLookupCode] => TP-AC1750
    [ManufacturerPartNumber] => Archer C7
    [ReorderNumber] => ARCHERC7
    [Notes] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [Description] => TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
    [ExtendedDescription] => TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless-AC1750 Dual-Band Gigabit Router
    [Quantity] => 0
    [SpoofStock] =>
    [Price] => 129.9500
    [PAM_Keywords] =>
    [PictureName] => tp-ac1750.jpg

  )

)
```

Comment: This isn't really what you're asking for, but it might be useful. http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2015/05/removing-duplicate-rows-from-2.html

Comment: There are some possibilities in that article. I will experiment and see what happens :) There is kind of a reoccurring theme with these methods, which I don't know how to do... Many of these functions like `array_merge_recursive` want two arrays passed to the function for comparison... I need to compare many arrays (not just two)...

Comment: You're still `INNER JOIN`ing and returning (potentially) many rows for each `Item` in a single result set. This is not what I recommended.

Comment: This question was asked before we began our discussion in the other thread :) So this was the initial query I had...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way I can think of:

```
<?php
$results = array(
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name1', 'ReorderNumber' => 1),
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name1', 'ReorderNumber' => 2),
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name1', 'ReorderNumber' => 3),
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name1', 'ReorderNumber' => 2),
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name2', 'ReorderNumber' => 1),
    array('ItemLookupCode' => 'name2', 'ReorderNumber' => 1),
);

function group($main, $item)  {
    if(!isset($main[$item['ItemLookupCode']])) {
        $main[$item['ItemLookupCode']] = array('ReorderNumber' => array());
    }
    if(!in_array($item['ReorderNumber'], $main[$item['ItemLookupCode']]['ReorderNumber'])) {
        $main[$item['ItemLookupCode']]['ReorderNumber'][] = $item['ReorderNumber'];
    }
    return $main;
}

$formatted_result = array();
foreach(array_reduce($results, "group") as $name => $item) {
    $formatted_result[] = array(
        'ItemLookupCode' => $name,
        'ReorderNumber' => $item
    );
}
print_r($formatted_result);
```

Comment: This actually puts the combined results into an array named `ReorderNumber` inside of a parent array named `ReorderNumber`. Comically, I cannot figure out how to bump the values from the child up a level into the parent...

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8265
            [ReorderNumber] => Array
                (
                    [ReorderNumber] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => N82E16833704177
                            [1] => 7681617
                            [2] => ARCHERC7 
                            [3] => ARCHERC7
                        )

                )

        )

)` I changed **ItemLookupCode** to **ID** btw.

Comment: How could I adjust this script so that there is not multiple levels of `ReorderNumber`?