# Merge Multiple Rows Based On Unique Identifier in SQL Server (GROUP_CONCAT for SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I was initially trying to figure this out via PHP, however I have not had much luck...

[How Can I Merge All Duplicates In Array Based On One Key's Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618297/how-can-i-merge-all-duplicates-in-array-based-on-one-keys-value/32618547#32618547)

Since I have not found a solution, I decided to try to solve my issue via my SQL query. What I need to know is how can I "merge" the differences between the returned rows in this query?

```
SELECT
  Item.ID,
  Item.ItemLookupCode,
  nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber,
  SupplierList.ReorderNumber,
  Item.Notes,
  Item.Description,
  Item.ExtendedDescription,
  Item.Quantity,
  nitroasl_pamtable.SpoofStock,
  Item.Price,
  nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords
FROM 
   Item
JOIN 
   nitroasl_pamtable ON Item.ID = nitroasl_pamtable.ItemID
JOIN 
   SupplierList ON Item.ID = SupplierList.ItemID
WHERE 
   (Item.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' 
    AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (SupplierList.ReorderNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 
    AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (Item.Notes LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (Item.Description LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (Item.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 
    AND WebItem = 1)
   OR 
   (nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 
    AND WebItem = 1)
ORDER BY 
    Item.ItemLookupCode ASC;
```

### What I think I need (but haven't successfully implemented)

MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) equivalent

I believe this function would do what I need, but I am using SQL Server - not MySQL. And I cannot seem to get the posted solutions on how to do this to work for me...

### What I've tried:

Recently, I tried the `MAX()` and the `GROUP BY` function (together), but it picks the `MAX` value that is returned in the duplicate rows, thus returning a single row with the `MAX` values in each column.

```
SELECT
    MAX(Item.ID) AS Id,
    Item.ItemLookupCode,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber) AS ManufacturerPartNumber,
    MAX(SupplierList.ReorderNumber) AS ReorderNumber,
    MAX( CAST(Item.Notes AS varchar(max)) ) AS Notes,
    MAX(Item.Description) AS Description,
    MAX( CAST(Item.ExtendedDescription AS varchar(max)) ) AS ExtendedDescription,
    MAX(Item.Quantity) AS Quantity,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.SpoofStock) AS SpoofStock,
    MAX(Item.Price) AS Price,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords) AS PAM_Keywords,
    MAX(Item.PictureName) AS PictureName
FROM 
    Item
LEFT JOIN 
    nitroasl_pamtable ON Item.ID = nitroasl_pamtable.ItemID
LEFT JOIN 
    SupplierList ON Item.ID = SupplierList.ItemID
WHERE 
    (Item.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (SupplierList.ReorderNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.Notes LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.Description LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
GROUP BY 
    Item.ItemLookupCode
ORDER BY 
    Item.ItemLookupCode ASC
```

Instead of discarding the variants of each column, I would like put all the returned values of each column (that are discarded with MAX) into their respective/original columns separated by a comma...

### What I need:

[Database Schema (Sample)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Et1xTmw3GYRkW9xIPyyFas1uItLQYyyIJddpR_IvZSg/edit?usp=sharing)

In the file above, you will see the four rows returned by the above SQL query. I would like to have **one row** returned that looks like this:

**ID:**

```
8265
```

**ItemLookupCode:**

```
TP-AC1750
```

**ManufacturerPartNumber:**

```
Archer C7
```

**ReorderNumber:**

```
7681617, ARCHERC7, N82E16833704177
```

**Notes:**

```
TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
```

**Description:**

```
TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750 Routr
```

**ExtendedDescription:**

```
TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless-AC1750 Dual-Band Gigabit Router
```

**Quantity:**

```
0 (This should actually be a combined sum/total of the values in this column)
```

**SpoofStock:**

```
NULL (Same as Quantity - Should be sum / This value is different than Quantity)
```

**Price:**

```
129.95
```

**PAM_Keywords:**

```
NULL
```

I know there is a better way to write this query. I am just not an SQL guy. This query/script is a keyword search that returns items in our Microsoft Dynamics RMS database, and outputs JSON that I use to create a list of products that can be changed and resubmitted to the DB. I use SQL Server 2008 R2 (if that matters). Any advice on how I can accomplish the above output using some variation of my query would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

## Update (SQLFiddle)

Here is a link to an SQLFiddle to play around with :)

[SQLFiddle with No MAX Function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/148c5/1)

[SQLFiddle with MAX Function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/148c5/2) (Not a viable solution as I lose data)

Comment: Look like you need XML and STUFF [example](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: I know I tried those at some point, but the example that I acquired the snippet from was much more complex than my query, and Ieverytime I remedied an error, another would pop up... Any insight into how I could integrate those functions into my query considering the dataTypes of my columns?

Comment: Your example is quite complex, maybe you could provide http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data and tables

Comment: I just added two SQLFiddles to my original post (see bottom). One is the base query (that returns multiple rows for one item), and the other is the current query I am using (that loses non "MAX" values - which is not what I want). Thanks for your time!

Comment: In the meantime, I will be reviewing that link you provided and trying to implement those functions. Thank you for the info!

Comment: You just need the `ReorderNumber` field concatenated? The rest of the query works just fine?

Comment: With the keyword I used in the example, there is only the one variation (`ReorderNumber`), however when other keywords are queried, the other columns may/will have variants as well... So no, not just `ReorderNumber`. I would like to use `ItemLookupCode` as the unique identifier for this. So if there were two rows, and all of the columns were the same (except `ItemLookupCode`), then the resulting output would render both rows. But if there are 6 rows, and each each individual column had a unique value, except `ItemLookupCode`, then 1 row would be output, but each column would be concatenated.

Comment: Can there be only one `ItemLookupCode` per `Item.ID`? If so, why would `Quantity` be a sum, as this would seem to multiply the item's quantity by the number of rows found, not a valid value?

Comment: That is another good point... I suppose I am just getting confused when I see 4 rows. In my mind: 4 rows = 4 separate items (that share an `ItemLookupCode`)... When in reality, it is 1 item that has 4 entries in the `SupplierList` table (which means 4 different `ReorderNumbers`). SO- **x1 ItemLookupCode per x1 ItemID**

Comment: So `Quantity`, `Price` and `SpoofStock` don't need to be concatenated...

Comment: Wait, `SpoofStock` is part of table `nitroasl_pamtable`. Can there be more than one row in that table for each `Item` row?

Comment: `SpoofStock` is an alternate quantity figure that is basically "our supplier's quantity in-stock". So, as with quantity, there should only be one row per `ItemID`/`ItemLookupCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started, but there is still some uncertainty around the `nitroasl_pamtable` table, so I didn't include that.

```
SELECT
  I.ID,
  I.ItemLookupCode,
  I.Notes,
  I.Description,
  I.ExtendedDescription,
  I.Quantity,
  I.Price,
  SL.ReorderNumbers,
  P.SpoofStock,
  P.ManufacturerPartNumber,
  P.PAM_Keywords
FROM
  Item I
  LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable P
    ON I.ID = P.ItemID
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      ReorderNumbers = Substring((
        SELECT DISTINCT Convert(varchar(max), ', ' + SL.ReorderNumber)
        FROM SupplierList SL
        WHERE I.ID = SL.ItemID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 3, 2147483647)
  ) SL
WHERE
  I.Price > 0.00
  AND I.WebItem = 1
  AND (
    I.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR I.Notes LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR I.Description LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR I.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR P.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR P.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    OR EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SupplierList SL2
      WHERE
        I.ID = SL2.ItemID
        AND SL2.ReorderNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  I.ItemLookupCode ASC;
```

To bring in `nitroasl_pamtable` correctly, for every column you want to concatenate, you could do a new `OUTER APPLY`. You can do a single `OUTER APPLY` to get at once all columns that need normal aggregation (such as `Sum()`).

However, I would like to offer that this concatenation will obscure the data in a way that could lead to incorrect assessment or decisions. Pulling in 3 values from a table and concatenating/summing them will make them appear to be a single unit, which may not be correct.

Another way that the concatenating may be harmful is with the reorder numbers. Notice that I put a `DISTINCT` in there because of the two duplicate reorder numbers--but they were from different suppliers. So what good is a reorder number apart from the supplier it can be sourced from? What if two different items have the same reorder number at different suppliers? (E.g., reorder number `BIGBOX` is a TV at one supplier, but it's a giant cardboard box at the other one.)

I am not convinced that it is a good idea to concatenate these values in the query. Instead, the UI should be presented the queries separately (the Items as one rowset, then the supporting data from each other table as individual rowsets) and then present the data in a way that makes sense in the UI.

Comment: Thank you for all of the recommendations. The idea of combining the values and concatenating the strings is more or less just to summarize the results found for any given `ItemLookupCode`. There is a second interface that is used later in the process. So the user searches, marks each `ItemLookupCode` they wish to add to "staging", then in staging, the various differences are displayed in a sensable manner. Basically, at a glance, the user needs to see the total combined data for said `ItemLookupCode`, but the data will be split at the next step...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am going to attempt to implement this, then I will hop back on and let you know how it goes. Thank you

Comment: Works great! Thanks a million! This is amazing.

Comment: If you are going to be splitting the data back out, then this approach is **definitely the wrong way to do it**. Please don't use these strings that way! You need to pull separate recordsets and use filtering to "join" them client-side. Please!

Comment: Okay, I DID ask about how to combine this data (in my php) but I haven't figured out how to accomplish modifying a single column in each row when using the SQLSRV/MSSQL driver... TBH, I was just planning on using a query similar to my original to output the separated data. How would you approach this?

Comment: I would put the results of the query against the `Item` table into a temp table. This would include no columns from any other table, but would use `EXISTS` like in my answer to include items that need to be included only because of values in other tables. Then I would select from the temp table, then do one select from each child table by `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Items I WHERE Outer.ItemID = I.ItemID)`. In your application, pull in all recordsets, then iterate over each `Item` and filter the secondary rowsets by `ItemID` and use them.

Comment: I like it. I will try that. I think it'll do the trick... I really appreciate your help with this. I learned a lot from this thread!

Comment: Please ask a new question if you are having trouble figuring out how to implement what I said. I don't know how to filter a recordset in PHP, but I imagine it can be done. Pseudocode: `For Item In ItemsRecordset { SupplierListRecordset.Filter = Format("ItemID = {0}", Item.ID); /* Use Item */ For Supplier In SupplierListRecordset { /* Use each Supplier */ } }`

Comment: Thanks, I asked how to do this with PHP in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618297/how-can-i-merge-all-duplicates-in-array-based-on-one-keys-value/32618547), but I didn't think the answer did what I needed... After discussing things with you, I realized `ReorderNumber` is the only value that will vary. HOWEVER, the response/answer I accepted produces a strange array that I cannot seem to get formatted the way I need... See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618297/how-can-i-merge-all-duplicates-in-array-based-on-one-keys-value/32618547#comment-53296562)

Comment: If you are also a PHP guy, you may understand what the functions do in that answer, I (for the most part) understand what it's doing, but when I try to adjust the resulting array, I start getting errors lol. Anyways, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, it looks like you just need to concatenate the `ReorderNumber` field. You could use a SQLCLR User-Defined Aggregate (UDA) to do this rather simply.

There is a pre-done UDA to do this called **Agg_Join** in the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library of SQLCLR functions, stored procedures, etc (that I am the author of, but this aggregate function is available in the Free version). Using it would make your query look as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(Item.ID) AS Id,
    Item.ItemLookupCode,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber) AS ManufacturerPartNumber,
    SQL#.Agg_Join(SupplierList.ReorderNumber) AS ReorderNumber,
    MAX( CAST(Item.Notes AS varchar(max)) ) AS Notes,
    MAX(Item.Description) AS Description,
    MAX( CAST(Item.ExtendedDescription AS varchar(max)) ) AS ExtendedDescription,
    MAX(Item.Quantity) AS Quantity,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.SpoofStock) AS SpoofStock,
    MAX(Item.Price) AS Price,
    MAX(nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords) AS PAM_Keywords,
    MAX(Item.PictureName) AS PictureName
FROM   Item
LEFT JOIN   nitroasl_pamtable
       ON Item.ID = nitroasl_pamtable.ItemID
LEFT JOIN  SupplierList
       ON Item.ID = SupplierList.ItemID
WHERE 
    (Item.ItemLookupCode LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (nitroasl_pamtable.ManufacturerPartNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
         AND Price > 0.00
         AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (SupplierList.ReorderNumber LIKE '%tp-ac1750%'
          AND Price > 0.00
          AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.Notes LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.Description LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (Item.ExtendedDescription LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
    OR (nitroasl_pamtable.PAM_Keywords LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)
GROUP BY      Item.ItemLookupCode
ORDER BY      Item.ItemLookupCode ASC;
```

Just to mention, the Full version of SQL# includes a more functional version of **Agg_Join** called **Agg_JoinPlus** that allows for sorting, filtering out duplicates, replacing `NULL`s, changing the delimiter, etc.

Or, if you want to create this on your own, in which case you can customize the functionality, I wrote an article showing an example of creating a User-Defined Aggregate that would just need to be altered a little to do string concatenation: [Getting The Most Out of SQL Server 2005 UDTs and UDAs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+CLR/3208/) (free registration is required). That was written prior to SQL Server 2008 coming out that had the ability to set `MaxSize` to `-1` so that it can store more than 8000 bytes at a time (which is more of an issue for this type of operation than it is for many arithmetic operations).

Another option that does not require subscriptions and should work out of the box (I haven't tried it myself) is this open-source project:

[GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)

This project has not been updated since 2013-05-09, but I suspect that it would do what you want and would fit into your query just like **SQL#.Agg_Join** and any other aggregate. There is an install script, **GroupConcatInstallation.sql**, in the **Installation Scripts** folder that contains the Assembly and T-SQL wrapper objects.

And yes, all of these aggregates should work with PHP or anything else since they are part of the query and hence it is SQL Server that does the processing and it has nothing to do with any particular client software.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I'm not sure if expanding our T-SQL library is an option for me. And it is a little strange that in order to view an answer, I have to register on your site, but I suppose a guy has to market, right? Thank you very much for your time, and we'll see how desperate I get trying to use native scripts lol. I may give in and take a peek :)

Comment: And I actually need to conduct the concatenation on all columns (except ItemLookupCode).

Comment: @derekmx271 It's not just marketing, it is a valid answer to a common enough issue :). And there isn't much I can do about that sites registration policy, BUT, I did just add a link to an open-source project that, while still being SQLCLR, it should be what you are looking for and free and no registrations :)

Comment: Have you considered that `(A LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1) OR (B LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' AND Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1)` might be more efficient as `Price > 0.00 AND WebItem = 1 AND (A LIKE '%tp-ac1750%' OR B LIKE '%tp-ac1750%')` ?

Comment: @srutzky - I was just giving you a hard time. No worries and again, I truely appreciate ANY help. I have been trying to crack this for a couple of days...

Comment: @ErikE - Lol wow, yes that would be much more intelligent. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @derekmx271 Ok, I was just covering my bases since there are some folks on here who are militantly against such things ;-). And I agree with ErikE's suggested improvement.

Comment: Oh buddy, I hear ya! I have been down-voted and accused of duplicating, etc. The mods are on their game- sometimes too much!

Comment: I meant to put my SQL comment on the original post, sorry about that.